# Log4net not able to write file

Tags: c#, asp.net, log4net

I am using log4net to log my project. I need to create multiple log files in my application. I am able to create the log file, but it seems log4net is not able to write.

Please see my coding below:

```cs
public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
{
    strLoadFilePath = @"E:\lewre\excel\stock\";
    strLoadFileName = @"iCenterProductConcept_*.xls";

    strCopyFilePath = @"E:\lewre\excel\stock\Processed\";
    strCopyFileName = @"iCenterProductConceptProcess_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm") + ".xls";

    //--Assign log4net path --
    log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["fileName"] = strCopyFilePath + "GeneralLog_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm");
    //log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["errorFileName"] = strCopyFilePath +"ErrorLog_"+ DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm");
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo("App.config"));
    ////**Assign log4net path **

    logger.Debug("test");
}
```

Log4net config:

```xml
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
    <section name="quartz" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.5000.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <sectionGroup name="common">
      <section name="logging" type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
    <section name="quartz" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.5000.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <sectionGroup name="common">
      <section name="logging" type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
  </appSettings>
  <!--<common>
    <logging>
      <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter,&#xD;&#xA;                        Common.Logging.Log4Net">
        <arg key="configType" value="INLINE" />
        <arg key="configFile" value="E:\\lewre\LewrerpLog\LewreQuartzLog.log" />
        <arg key="level" value="ALL" />
      </factoryAdapter>
    </logging>
  </common>-->
  <log4net>


<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{fileName}.txt"/>
  <appendToFile value="false"/>
  <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1"/>
  <maximumFileSize value="1024KB"/>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %logger - %message%newline"/>
  </layout>

  <filter type="log4net.Filter.PropertyFilter">
    <Key value="Version" />
    <StringToMatch value="1" />
  </filter>
</appender>

  <root>
    <level value="All" />
    <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />      
  </root>
</log4net>
```

Comment: have you tried inside your logger.Debug method the follwing
EventLog.WriteEntry(source, text, EventLogEntryType.Error);

Answer (score 1):

To configure log for net, you only need to add

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
[assembly: log4net.Config.Repository()]
namespace MyApp
{
    public class Main
    {
       private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Main));
    }
}
```

This needs to be executed only once for your application.

The date pattern you want to write your log files can be created using the `DatePattern`.

```xml
 <appender name="A1" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="E:\lewre\excel\stock\Processed\GeneralLog_" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <staticLogFileName value="false" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="yyyyMMddHHmm'.txt'" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
```

Comment: Hi , i need to create dynamic file.For example i may create GeneralLog_1234.log or ErrorLog_1234.log

Comment: That too can be handled through configuration. You need to have multiple appenders, and filter messages that each appender should log. That you can change which messages get logged through configuration when required. Take a look at this example to get started: http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2003/06/16/log4net.html?page=2

Comment: Hi. I only able to create the log File but not able to write any text

Comment: Try with a simple file appender first. If the file is getting created, log4net has all permissions to write. Check that the appender name in root, matches appender name you have given. Also set the logging level to `All` to test it.

Comment: ok. it able to work already btw if i want to assign debug mode write to  debug log file . Other than debug mode write to general log file. How to set for the logging level? 
<root>  <level value="All" />
  <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />


</root>